# Velocity of propagation of an EM field in vacuum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, speed-of-light, velocity

I am asked to find the speed of propagation $\vec{v}$ of an electromagnetic field, in a region of empty space. The magnetic field is described by $\vec{B} = B_0e^{ax}\sin{(ky-\omega t)} \hat{z}$.

I know the magnetic field satisfies the wave equation
$$\Delta \vec{B} = \frac{1}{v^2}\frac{d^2\vec{B}}{dt^2}$$ , $k=\frac{\omega }{ v}$

But I'm not sure how to calculate the velocity. Do I have to take into account the equation, or because the wave is propagating in empty space can I simply say $v=c$? And I know the direction of propagation would be $\hat{y}$ if the term $e^{ax}$ didn't exist, but is it still $\hat{y}$ with it? I really don't understand how that term affects the velocity of propagation.

Answer (score -1):

The B-field is travelling in the positive y direction (the sin term) and a displacement in z direction with an amplitude  which varies with x, increasing exponentially with increasing x.
So the speed of the wave can be relatively easily determined?

Comment: Ok, so the x only affects the amplitude but not the speed. Then the direction of $\vec{v}$ is $\hat{y}$. But I still don't understand how to calculate the speed.

Comment: As ever, I would like to know the reason for the down vote over five ears after I wrote an answer..